# Adding a square in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a square in JavaScript. I have made a class in CSS with square. I want to create something like a `<div class="square></div>` so that the square is displayed when I click on the button. I have tried using `createElement` and passing the statement as `innerHTML`. However that didn't seem to work. Can someone help me in suggesting what I am missing? I am trying to create a matrix of squares using the number input by the user

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<!-- <meta charset="utf-8" /> -->
<title>Form Validation</title>
<script>
    function validateForm()
    {
        var x = document.forms["MyForm"]["Numval"].value;

        if ((!x.match(/^\d+/)) || ((x.length) > 1)) {
            alert("Please only one enter numeric character (Allowed input:1-9)");
        }
        else {
            for (i = 0; i < Number(x) ; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < Number(x) ; j++) {
                    document.writeln(x);

                    var square = document.createElement('div');
                    square.className = 'squared';
                    document.body.appendChild(square)

                }
                document.writeln("</br>");
                }

        }

        return false;

    }
</script>



<style type="text/css">
.squared {
border: 2x solid black;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background:black;
color:black;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<form name="MyForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" >


    Please enter a number between 1-9 : 
    <input type ="text" name="Numval"/>
   <input type="Submit" value="Submit" />


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We can't help figure out what's wrong if you don't post your code.

Comment: Could you show us the code?

Comment: Very vague, but many options. Probably easiest is to create a css class called "square". Then create an element and give it the class square.

Answer (score 1):

```
var square = document.createElement('div');
square.className = 'square';
document.body.appendChild(square);
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ysw9n/

Comment: i have added my code above... but the square are not getting displayed... can u please tell me what's the issue?

Comment: @JackSmith - Well, it works for me. Check out the fiddle I just added to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I found out that document.writeln was kinda overwriting the whole page as the result of which the square wasn't getting displayed. I will have to figure out a way to add a tab space between squares. Thanks a lot for your help. Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use jquery it's really a simple thing to do:

```
$("#your-button-id").click(function() { 
   $("#your-square-parent-id").append('<div class="your-square-class">&nbsp;</div>');
});
```

But you can do that without jquery as well as Joseph stated above. Anyways, hope it is useful.

Comment: No need for the inner call to jQuery. Just pass the HTML string directly to `append`.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my answer properly. Didn't know that append was smart enough to do that.

Comment: Actually, it's smarter than you think: You can even omit the closing tag.